# Extracting Resources relative to classpath

Tags: java, spring, embedded-resource

I am trying to extract certain types of file from my classpath and put to a temp directory, and I want the resources to be extracted according to its "relative path to classpath".

I am able to use Spring's PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver to retrieve list of matching resources.  For example, I am scanning for `classpath*:/xyz/**/*.bar` from the classpath, assume in classpath I have a `/xyz/some/dir/foo.bar`, and I want to extract this resource to `MY_TEMP_DIR/some/dir/foo.bar`.  Is there anyway to get the relative path of this resource to classpath so I can construct the output location accordingly?

PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver is only returning array of Resource, for which I can only retrieve the URL of the resources, but I want to know also what's the "root" directory of this resources.  The Resource returned can be in various "format", like `jar:file:/some/path/somejar.jar!/xyz/some/dir/foo.bar`, `file:/some/output/directory/xyz/some/dir/foo.bar` etc.

Can someone give me hints on how to achieve the extracting or classpath-root-relative-path lookup of a resource?

Thanks

---

***Edit:***

I am not sure if it is better if I put my question in another way:

Is there any way to know what's the "relative path to classpath" of a resource?
Just use my previous examples, if I scan `classpath*:/xyz/**/*.bar`, and I get a resource `file:/some/output/directory/xyz/some/dir/foo.bar`, is there any way I can get the "relative path" of that resource (`/xyz/some/dir/foo.bar`) ?

Comment: *"I am trying to extract certain types of file from my classpath and put to a temp directory,"*  Why?  What feature does it offer the user?

Comment: Now I am using that for solving a technical deficiency of a lib I am using, which they didn't work well in getting resource from classpath. I want to get the bundled resources to a local directory and let the lib read it from there instead.  However I believe this is not the only case I need such feature, I encountered other cases in my past that I want to extract resources from classpath yet to maintain its original "directory" structure.

Answer (score 1):

You you use the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(String pattern)` to get a list of resources matching the pattern, it should be trivial to parse the URL returned by Resource.getURL().

It should look something like `jar:file://path/to/jar.jar!/path/to/your/resource/foo.bar`

Comment: If you have read in my question, you should know that my question is not about how to get the resource, but how to get the "path" of it so I can maintain the directory structure when I extract.  Parsing JAR URLs are easy, but what about a file?  Given a `file:/a/b/c/d/e/Foo.bar`, how should I know it is `/e/Foo.bar` under directory '/a/b/c/d' , or it is `/b/c/d/e/Foo.bar` under `/a` ?